# How can we make purchase order optional in magento 2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, payment-methods, purchase-order

Is there a way to make the purchase order number in the checkout page optional? 
without filling purchase order number text field, I want to place an  order.

[image]

Comment: have you found the solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to override the Model,
in your di.xml

```
preference for="Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Purchaseorder" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Purchaseorder"
```

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class Purchaseorder extends \Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Purchaseorder {

    public function validate()
    {
        //parent::validate();

        if (empty($this->getInfoInstance()->getPoNumber())) {
            //throw new LocalizedException(__('Purchase order number is a required field.'));
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Comment: what about admin orders?

Comment: @codealliance_dev I have tried this but it's not working. Can you please help on this?

Comment: @Siv I had an error in the di.xml, fixed it, can you send me your code for these 2 fragments and tell me what version of Magento you are using?

Comment: @codealliance_dev I am using the Magento version: 2.4.2-p2. Can you please update the code?

Comment: @codealliance_dev I have posted the question, can you please add your solution there? It would be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to remove the data-validate="{required:true}" from the input field. 
File path magento/module-offline-payments/view/frontend/web/template/payment/purchaseorder-form.html and also remove required class.

Comment: I tried this code but its not working.

Comment: Hi @kiran, it's working fine on my side.

Answer (score 0):

Now in Magento 2.4.6 (maybe previous) you need to do the following:

Copy:
`vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/view/frontend/web/template/payment/purchaseorder-form.html`

To: `app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_OfflinePayments/web/template/payment/purchaseorder-form.html`

In: `app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_OfflinePayments/web/template/payment/purchaseorder-form.html`

Remove: `data-validate="{required:true}"`

Create (or edit if exists): `app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/di.xml`

with code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Purchaseorder">
        <plugin name="purchase_order_validate" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Purchaseorder"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement">
        <plugin name="validate_purchase_order_number" disabled="true"/>
    </type>

</config>
```

Create: `app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/Plugin/Model/Purchaseorder.php`

with code:

```
<?php 

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Model;

class Purchaseorder
{
    public function aroundvalidate($subject, $proceed)
    {
        // check PoNumber is empty or not
        if (empty($subject->getInfoInstance()->getPoNumber())) {
            return $this;
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

All being well, that should not only take care of removing the validation for the Purchase Order Number on the fronted, but should also remove the backend validation done through AJAX.